# Is there a self contained library for serializing PHP data to AMF?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, rest, amf

My team has been asked to offer AMF output from our web service to decrease the time spent parsing XML or JSON for Flash modules on the front end.

As we have an existing application architecture that we must continue to support in terms of request structure etc, I am not interested in using one of the preexisting AMF RPC frameworks (eg: AMFphp).

Our application is written in PHP, so a PHP library we can implement directly would be best.  Does anyone know of a library that can accomplish this without major refactoring?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you can use `Zend_Amf` and remove all the "controller" parts of `Zend_Amf_Server` to keep only the `Zend_Amf_Response` class itself. The code to `Zend_Amf_Server` should be reasonably documented.

Comment: This is looking promising, thank you.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.server.html